# Using pdfminer on screenplay to output to csv

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, pdfminer

I am attempting to use pdfminer on a screenplay of a television show. The ideal output would be a csv file with one column being the character names, and the other column the lines that they spoke.

Here is a link to an dialogue excerpt from the screenplay. 
[Dialogue From Screenplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOvuo.png)

Because of the unique structure of the script, just reading the text from the pdf is not enough to distinguish which parts are the narrations, and which parts are the dialogue. With the below code, I identified individual text objects and printed out their coordinates.

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

fp = open('Ozark-Episode-1-01-Sugarwood.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for index, page in enumerate(pages):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lobj in layout:
        if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
            x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
            print('%r: %s' % ((round(x, 1), round(y,1)), text)
```

However, here is an example of what was returned:

```
(108.0, 579.9): No, it wasn’t--

(194.0, 591.9): MARTY

(333.0, 591.9): BRUCE
Sorry, all right?

(252.0, 555.9): BRUCE

(180.0, 543.9): What then?  A place like this 
validates us.  We’re making money 
hand over fist.  Tell me we don’t 
need the higher rent on our books.

(108.0, 483.9): Marty squares up to the skyline, Bruce behind him.
```

As can be seen, the order of the lines are mixed up right now. I was intending to read the text into csv line by line in a specific order but whenever two characters speak at the same time, the pdf reads the objects differently. Additionally, at (333.0, 591.9) where Bruce speaks, the pdf is not able to read the dialogue as a separate line from the character. I predict there will be many such problems in the screenplay format.

I would greatly appreciate any help whatsoever on how the lines can be read in a chronological order, or how to better be able to distinguish between character and dialogue in an easy and orderly manner.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Break every box into lines. Sort lines by y coordinate. If there is one name textline in a current y block, take all the next lines until empty block starts as lines for the current character. If there are two name textlines then split all the next lines into two halves by their x coordinate and so on. If two vertically adjacent lines are put into one `LTTextline` try changing `line_margin` in `LAParams()`.

Comment: @hellpanderr thank you for this! I managed to do it with your advice